# Paths returned by RecursiveDirectoryIterator not working

Tags: php, laravel

I'm fetching a directory using `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` and it works fine:

```php
$photosPath = storage_path('photos');

$directoryIteratorOptions = (
    RecursiveDirectoryIterator::CURRENT_AS_PATHNAME |
    RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS
);

$directoryIterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator(
    $photosPath,
    $directoryIteratorOptions
);

$recursiveIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($directoryIterator);

foreach ($recursiveIterator as $filePath) {
    $exists = file_exists($filePath); // true
    var_dump($exists);
}
```

But when I want to get the mime type, I'm getting a `Failed to open stream: No such file or directory` error:

```
foreach ($recursiveIterator as $filePath) {
    // Example: /var/www/html/storage/photos/moon.png

    $mime = mime_content_type($filePath); // error
    var_dump($mime);
}
```

What is going on? I'm using Laravel Sail as a web server.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Dumping `$filePath` could already help to check what that variable contains

Comment: possibly wrong file path! Don't use relative paths when working with Laravel. Common mistakes that people do and end up passing incorrect file paths. Use helper methods instead.

Comment: @NicoHaase I'm asking if the path returned by `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` is somewhat different than what file tools in PHP expect. It returns absolute paths on my server.

Comment: And you checked that the file that should be opened exists with the given path?

Comment: @OMiShah this is just an example, in reality I'm using `storage_path()` there. The paths returned by the iterator are absolute anyway.

Comment: @NicoHaase I included `file_exists()` call in the snippet if you missed it.

Comment: And `file_exists` always yields true, while `mime_content_type` always throws the error? If you used the path directly (without the iterator), does it throw the same error?

Comment: @NicoHaase what do you mean? The path is just a string.

Comment: @NicoHaase I added an example. The paths start with `/var/www/html/storage/photos/`

Comment: And if you used the path that is returned by the iterator and call `mime_content_type` with that string, without using any iterator, does that work? Is that file maybe part of a symlink?

Comment: @NicoHaase that's a weird question. Of course it behaves the same if I pass the same string manually.

Comment: Why should that be a weird question? Now you know that the problem is not related to the iterator itself. Please add these details to your question by editing it

Comment: with all the details you have shared so far, it is weird to have such an issue tbh. Is there anything else you're doing in between?

Comment: It's silly to say but might be ``moon.png`` (for e.g.) corrupted? If the file is totally fine, then check for sufficient file permission.

Comment: *"Of course it behaves the same if I pass the same string manually."* If the issue is not related to `RecursiveDirectoryIterator`, then why is your title "Paths returned by RecursiveDirectoryIterator not working"? Why pollute the question with something irrelevant? And why the Laravel tag?

Comment: should that not be along the lines of `mime_content_type( $filePath->getPathName() )` ?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius, The code is correct. Probably it has something to do with the file or might be path is directory instead. Or even the file mighube corrupted.

Comment: @OMiShah - my mistake - I overlooked the `CURRENT_AS_PATHNAME` flag. I'm so used to using `KEY_AS_PATHNAME`

Comment: @Olivier because I'm using Laravel Sail, which I forgot to mention. Not sure how relevant that is.

Comment: Please try to check what `mime_content_type('/var/www/html/storage/photos/moon.png');` returns. Also, please share whether you are using any kind of symlinks, or whether that file has any unusual permission setting. If you opened it anywhere else, does it show a proper image?